# How to read the response data of Apollo Client response/ GraphQL response in Kotlin Andorid

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, apollo-client

I am developing an Android application using Kotlin. In my application, I am consuming GraphQL API using Apollo Client. What I am trying to do now is that I want to retrieve a response field of the response.

This is my code

```
protected fun _handleLoginButtonClick(view: View) {
        val apolloClient = ApolloClient.builder()
            .serverUrl("https://app.herokuapp.com/graphql")
            .okHttpClient(OkHttpClient())
            .build()
        val loginMutation = LoginMutation.builder()
            .identity(view.etf_email.text.toString())
            .password(view.etf_password.text.toString())
            .build()

        view.tv_login_error_message.text = "Started making request"
        apolloClient.mutate(loginMutation).enqueue(object: ApolloCall.Callback<LoginMutation.Data>() {
            override fun onFailure(e: ApolloException) {
                view.tv_login_error_message.text = e.message

            }

            override fun onResponse(response: Response<LoginMutation.Data>) {
                //here I dont know how to retrieve a field, accessToken
            }
        })
    }
```

As you can see the comment in the onResponse callback, I cannot figure out how to retrieve the accessToken field. How can I retrieve it?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? You should have code completion that will suggest the available properties and methods once you type the period after `response`. Because `data` is always nullable, you may have to use the safe call operator (i.e. type `?.` instead of just `.`) to see the options populate. You can also just view the generated `LoginMutation.Data` class yourself.

Answer (score 0):

OnResponse Contains response Object and it has data object from where you can get your fields.

apolloClient.mutate(loginMutation).enqueue(object: ApolloCall.Callback<LoginMutation.Data>() {
override fun onFailure(e: ApolloException) {
view.tv_login_error_message.text = e.message

```
        }

        override fun onResponse(response: Response<LoginMutation.Data>) {
            //here you can use response to get your model data like accessToken
           response.data.(here you can get data from your model. eg accessToken)
        }
    })
```